# Reversing an array manually

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I am learning JS and stuck on this thing. I need to reverse an array with function that takes an argument as value. Like this:

```
value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverse(value);
console.log(value);
//[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I wrote this function and can't understand why it won't work:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(x){
  var p = 0, y = x;
  for(i = y.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    x[p] = y[i];
    p++;
    }
  return x;
  }
```

It s returning this: [5, 4, 3, 4, 5]
Maybe I've done something stupid in here, but still can you point me where is the mistake? 
Thank you!

Comment: `y = x` doesn't copy the array, it just creates a second reference to it. Don't forget to declare *i* as well.

Comment: I hope this is just some "exercise" - because [Array#reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
var p = 0, y = x;
```

Is storing a reference to the array stored in `x`, into the variable `y`. In other words, `x` and `y` are pointing to *the same array*.

To fix this, build a new array:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(x) {
    var p = 0, y = [];

    for (i = x.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        y[p] = x[i];
        p++;
    }
    return y;
}
```

If you absolutely need to modify the original array, just copy the reversed array back into the original:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(x) {
    var p = 0, y = [];

    for (i = x.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        y[p] = x[i];
        p++;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        x[i] = y[i];
    }

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could loop until the middle of the modified array. And simply swap elements

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(x) {
  for (var i = 0, last = x.length - 1, mid = last/2, tmp; i <= mid; i++) {
    tmp = x[i];
    x[i] = x[last - i];
    x[last - i] = tmp;
    
  }
  return x;
}

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

reverseArrayInPlace(arr)

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

reverseArrayInPlace(arr2)

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2))
```

Comment: As author is only studiyng I'd suggest to make your solution more simple. Or to explain it at least.

Comment: @blewherself Which part do you think requires additional explanation?

Comment: This. `for (var i = 0, len = x.length, mid = len/2|0, tmp; i < mid; i++)` Also, using JSON.strngify methods seems confusing

Comment: @blewherself I have simplified variable definition to use last index instead of array length. `stringify` was used to make SO console wrapper to print array in one line and is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I can get it. But I suppose this simplification can make it harder to read for people that are still learning. Nevermind

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the original array as well, when you write `y=x` as they are copied by reference.

Instead do this:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(x) {
  var p = 0, y = [];
  for (i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    y[p] = x[i];
    p++;
  }
  return y;
}

console.log(reverseArrayInPlace([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Comment: Thing is - I need to modify the original array :) Maybe it's not very practical but it's for education purpose

Comment: In that case , just do the same at the end   `x = y` and then `return x`

Comment: @SandeepNayak that's just overwriting the reference, not modifying the original array (so if the array is used outside the function it won't hold the new array order).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are overriding the original array so you need to clone the array to temporary variable and then ressign the values

```
value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

but you can do this directly with this function

```
console.log(value.reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this this will replace original array as per your requirement:

```
value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
value = value.reverse();
console.log(value);
```

or you can do like this:

```js
value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverse(value);
console.log(value);

function reverse(x) {
  var p = 0, y = [];
  for (i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    y[p] = x[i];
    p++;
  }
  value = y;
}
```

Comment: Those are not equivalent. One will reverse the array, the other will create a new array that is the reverse of the first array.